FATAL: role "***" does not exist
I have just installed PostgreSQL on my machine.
psql --version psql returns  (PostgreSQL) 16.2 (Ubuntu 16.2-1.pgdg22.04+1)
I'm trying to create a database but this error is prompted:
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "***" does not exist

I've checked for postgresql.service and it is active.
I have also ran this postgres=# CREATE ROLE *** but I still get the error.

Please describe in detail how exactly you're trying to create a database, naming the tools/options/commands you used that lead to this error. Make sure you don't have multiple database clusters/servers running on different ports, in which case you could be running commands against one of them, then expecting them to be applied to the other one. If you really want to have a role named *** you need to create role "***"; (wrap it in double quotes): demo.
